# Resizable DIV inside DIV 100% height with margin around not working well! Some help please?

Tags: css, html, height

This is a common question but slightly different from the solutions I found and I've been trying to solve it without success, so if someone could give me a help on this I would appreciate.

I have a #wrapper div that stretches to 100% width and height of browser. So far, so good... Now, inside the #wrapper I need a #content div that auto stretches with the parent div maintaining a 30px margin around it. I (almost) managed to do it but I can't make the #content div stretch in its height. 
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image: example]

This is the CSS code I have:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="content">
    This DIV should stretch to 100% height of its parent and body 
    minus the 30px margin around and resize as the window is resized.<br />
    It's working in width but not in height!<br /><br />
    Whatever goes in here (a child DIV) no matter its size should not be 
    visible beyond this DIV boundaries (as the Overflow is set to "hidden")!
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

And this is what I'm getting in both Chrome and IE:

[image: current result in Chrome and IE]

Any help on this? Is it possible? Am I missing something stupid?

Thanks in advance,
LM

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/wbRwS/  Check this..

Comment: Well, sorry I didn't mentioned but I also tried that approach before posting here, it doesn't work because I need the margins to be a fixed value (ex: 30px) and percent will mess it up when the window is resized! Also, somehow the width is not right, it bounces more to the left... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .css, replace `#content` with the following

```
#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;  
}
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT :) it works just as I needed! One of those CSS misleads, I began thinking of width, height and margins and it didn't even came to my mind that approach. So simple... that I feel dumb!

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
  min-height:90%;
  position:absolute;
  margin: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work... exactly the same as I posted in comment above. I need a fixed value margin not percentage. Any other trick?!